# Найти ближайший элемент на странице

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

Добрый день, помогите найти ближайший элемент на странице с помощью JavaScript. Сейчас у меня находит ближайший элемент только по X. Бот у которого 75 score побежит вверх потому-что по X ему ближе, но на самом деле ближе совсем другой элемент на странице (тот coin что правее).
Вот код:

```
const closest = (a,g) => a.reduce((p,c) => Math.abs(c-g) < Math.abs(p-g) ? c : p);

let botPositionX = parseInt(64);
let botPositionY = parseInt(64);
const data = [{x: 500, y: 285}, {x: 200, y: 324}, {x: 700, y: 200}];
const dataX = [500, 200, 700];
const dataY = [285, 324, 200];
const rightOrLeft = closest(dataX, botPositionX);
const topOrBottom = closest(dataY, botPositionY);

let found = data.find((loc) => {
  return loc.x === rightOrLeft;
});

let coinPosX = parseInt(found.x);
let coinPosY = parseInt(found.y);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно искать расстояние по прямой, учитывая положение по X  и Y.
Формула нахождения длины по координатам:  `длина отрезка² = (y2 - y1)² + (x2 - x1)²`
На JS это выглядит так:

```
var g  = (Math.pow(x2-x1,2))+(Math.pow(y2-y1,2));
var dlina = Math.sqrt(g);
```

Comment: В принципе понятно, нашел самое минимальное значение, но как теперь понять к какому ключу с {x,y} минимальное значение относиться?

Comment: Где у Вас хранятся координаты ключей? Используйте доп. объект, с координатами, где будут записаны все координаты

Comment: const data = [{x: 500, y: 285}, {x: 200, y: 324}, {x: 700, y: 200}];

Comment: Напишите функцию, которая будет поочередно находить расстояние и записывать данные в промежуточный массив или объект. Потом используйте меньшее...